# Sequence of When-Button-Pressed Button Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have "UPLOAD" Button on Oracle Forms in which when user press the button then:

If "Text Item" Field NOT NULL Then

-- Run Upload Procedure From "CSV" File to Oracle Forms

-- Save Data From Oracle Forms to Table in Database

-- Run report in Excel File From SQL QUERY

-- Change the label of Upload Button to "Upload[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1azQg.png)"

**These steps Run Successfully. Code:**

```
IF ( :WE_GROUP_HOF_K.FILE IS NOT NULL ) THEN
EXCEL_UPLOAD;
commit;
REPORT_EXCEL;
Set_Item_Property('Upload',label,'Upload [1]');

END IF;
```

[image]

Now I want these steps When user again Press "UPLOAD" Button:

If Upload Button = 1 Like "Upload [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1azQg.png)" THEN

-- Delete from table

-- Upload Again (Run Upload Procedure)

-- Save data into table database

-- Change the label of Upload Button to "Upload[2]"

I tried myself When Upload Button Label "Upload[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1azQg.png)" Then run 2nd steps but did not solved. Please Provide Solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `Get_Item_Property` method to extract the `numeric part` for your `if statement` as

```
declare
  v_label varchar2(100);
begin
 if ( :we_group_hof_k.file is not null ) then
 begin   
  v_label := Get_Item_Property('Upload',label);
  if regexp_replace(v_label,'(\D)') = '1' then
    Delete from table ...
    EXCEL_UPLOAD;
    Save data into table database ...    
    Set_Item_Property('Upload',label,'Upload [2]');
  else
    EXCEL_UPLOAD;
    REPORT_EXCEL;
    Set_Item_Property('Upload',label,'Upload [1]');      
  end if;
    commit;
 end;   
 end if; 
end;
```